# Regular expression of -digit

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that will match strings like : -2,-3,-10,-100 ...

I know that the regular expression of number is `\\d` but how can i say the negation before it?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Allow me to Google for you: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regex%20negative%20number

Comment: Did you try out whether `"-"` matches the minus sign?  Or look at the Javadoc for the `Pattern` class?

Comment: I'm sorry it was my fault because of bad googling, I'm a beginner  @tnw

Comment: No I don't know how can I search in Javadoc for pattern Class. Can you help me?@DavidWallace

Comment: @user3813380 Have we not learned? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javadoc%20pattern%20class First result...

Comment: Yes we have.tnx -tnw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming  you don't want to match strings like `"-0"` and `"-0123"`, you probably want the expression

```
"-[1-9]\\d*"
```

which requires you to have a minus sign, a digit from 1 to 9, and then any number of additional digits - or none of them.  The additional digits might include 0.  The first backslash is there to escape the second one; and strictly speaking isn't part of the regular expression.

Comment: what does * do after d?

Comment: @user3813380 You display many symptoms of being a [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/), particularly due to your lack of Googling or reading the documentation. Your adventures in SO will be more fruitful if you rectify your vampiric tendencies as the community is vigilant against the continued threat of vampire infestations which typically permeate the more popular communities.

Comment: No really I'm not Help Vampire, my question is because of my hurry . I didn't have enough time to search. but I accept I'm not good at Googling and I must try more.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist for the benefit of those who are in too much of a hurry to find their own answers.  You won't necessarily find someone here who is in less of a hurry than you are.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regular expression:

```
"-\\d+"
```

Equivalently:

```
"-[0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
-\\d+
```

Code:

```
System.out.println("-100".matches("-\\d+"));
System.out.println("-13".matches("-\\d+"));
System.out.println("13-".matches("-\\d+"));
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```